# Bootstrap 5.3.2 Custom Theme doesn't work

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm not quite sure to understand how to create and add a custom data-bs-theme in Bootstrap 5.3.2.I tried to override all CSS color variables this way :

```
[data-bs-theme="leev-dark"] {
  --bs-body-color: #e2e2e2;
  --bs-body-color-rgb: to-rgb(#e2e2e2);
  --bs-body-bg: #323232;
  --bs-body-bg-rgb: to-rgb(#323232);
  --bs-secondary-color: #ffffff;
  --bs-secondary-color-rgb: to-rgb(#ffffff);
  --bs-secondary-bg: #6e6c6d;
  --bs-secondary-bg-rgb: to-rgb(#6e6c6d);
  --bs-tertiary-color: #e2e2e2;
  --bs-tertiary-color-rgb: to-rgb(#e2e2e2);
  --bs-tertiary-bg: #4f4f4f;
  --bs-tertiary-bg-rgb: to-rgb(#4f4f4f);
  --bs-emphasis-color: #ffffff;
  --bs-emphasis-color-rgb: to-rgb(#ffffff);
  --bs-border-color: #6e6c6d;
  --bs-border-color-rgb: to-rgb(#6e6c6d);
  --bs-primary: #e16daa;
  --bs-primary-rgb: to-rgb(#e16daa);
  --bs-primary-bg-subtle: #712856;
  --bs-primary-border-subtle: #f392c8;
  --bs-primary-text-emphasis: #f392c8;
  --bs-success: #46bc7f;
  --bs-success-rgb: to-rgb(#46bc7f);
  --bs-success-bg-subtle: #0f3a26;
  --bs-success-border-subtle: #277a50;
  --bs-success-text-emphasis: #a9ead4;
  --bs-danger: #e74f64;
  --bs-danger-rgb: to-rgb(#e74f64);
  --bs-danger-bg-subtle: #811232;
  --bs-danger-border-subtle: #ef7189;
  --bs-danger-text-emphasis: #f4ccd5;
  --bs-warning: #ffb353;
  --bs-warning-rgb: to-rgb(#ffb353);
  --bs-warning-bg-subtle: #744916;
  --bs-warning-border-subtle: #cc8631;
  --bs-warning-text-emphasis: #f7d5af;
  --bs-info: #3fa1c8;
  --bs-info-rgb: to-rgb(#3fa1c8);
  --bs-info-bg-subtle: #4f5ca2;
  --bs-info-border-subtle: #27829f;
  --bs-info-text-emphasis: #89d1e9;
  --bs-light: #ffffff;
  --bs-light-rgb: to-rgb(#ffffff);
  --bs-light-bg-subtle: #8a8a8a;
  --bs-light-border-subtle: #c4c4c4;
  --bs-light-text-emphasis: #e2e2e2;
  --bs-dark: #4f4f4f;
  --bs-dark-rgb: to-rgb(#4f4f4f);
  --bs-dark-bg-subtle: #323232;
  --bs-dark-border-subtle: #6e6c6d;
  --bs-dark-text-emphasis: #ffffff;
}
```

And it's doesn't work when I apply `data-bs-theme="leev-dark"` to an element.

For example, this :

```
<body data-bs-theme="dark">
    <a class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill m-5" href="#" role="button">Button</a>
</body>
```

Give me this :

[image: Dark Theme Primary Button Bootstrap 5.3.2]

but this :

```
<body data-bs-theme="leev-dark">
    <a class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill m-5" href="#" role="button">Button</a>
</body>
```

Give me this :

[image: Custom Theme Primary Button Bootstrap 5.3.2]

But the background color should be `#323232` and the button color `#e16daa` : [See colors on coolors.co](https://coolors.co/323232-e16daa)

I think I'm missing something, any help is welcome !

I probably need to add some sass to include my theme but I don't really understand how to do this, despite the Bootstrap Documentation.

Thanks.